# How can I filter a View by the value (or data) of field?

Tags: entities, views

This seams like quite a basic thing but I cannot work out how to do this in Views, since the Views filter criteria has no option to use the data/value from a specific field or token. There is only an option to add a constant value or to expose the field, neither of which are useful in my case.

[image]

I have a list of entities which I would like to filter based on the value of a node field; and this value is auto assigned through a default token set in the content type. The field is a plain text field with a date in it, which I would like to use to filter my list of entities to only show the entities created on that particular date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked out how to do this finally. You need to install the token filter module and then when entering a value for a filter inside Views, you can make the operator "equal to" a token. Meaning, you can filter by the value of a particular field or anything else exposed as a token.

Comment: Can you explain more? I've tried this just now in D7 and views 3, and I don't see how 'make the operator "equal to" a token'.