# Filter criteria "Now" doesn't work on submitted data for field:event date

Tags: views, webforms

The closest I have found to this is [How can I filter a View by the value (or data) of field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/110310/how-can-i-filter-a-view-by-the-value-or-data-of-field) which sounded perfect but it didn't work for me.

I need to show a list of values equal to or greater than today's date. For dates in the past, on a value formatted as a date, I use `now` and it works.

I built a view using webform submission data from the latest webform release, which enters a date field as text, for example *2014-05-08*, into the database rather than a timestamp.

I can test it by entering the date into the filter value as *2014-05-08* and it works perfectly, but of course I need today's date to update automatically.

I tried using the token filter (*Y-m-d*) to get the current date, but nothing happens.

I have also installed the *Views PHP* module, but the following code didn't work.

```php
$date = date('Y-m-d');  
if ($row > value_1 == $date) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Is there a way to use tokens in the *Configure filter criterion: value* field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand the problem. When a date isn't a date anymore and you can use php you can just convert it back to a date.

You even almost use the correct function.

```
$submittedDate = $row>value_1;

$Cdate = date('Y-m-d');
$Sdate = date_format(date_create($submittedDate), 'Y-m-d');

if ($Sdate == $Cdate) {
    return TRUE;
}
```

Shouldn't that do the trick?

Comment: Yeah that looks ideal, but its having no effect on the results. I want to create an exposed filter for the field "event date" and show results for today and tomorrow, based on "now" and "now + 1 day". Is there anyway to convert the text into a date format, and then filter by that? That's the reason I thought printing the token in the value field might be a better way of doing it.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction, there was a bug in the views-php module that was returning the node ID for every value, so no wonder it wasnt converting it to a date! That was driving me nuts!